# Quotient of a Euclidean domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, euclidean-algorithm

> Let $A$ be a Euclidean domain such that its only invertible elements are $1$ and $-1$, and let $\varphi : A^* \to \mathbb{N}$ be a Euclidean function. Show that if $a \in A^*$ is a non-invertible element for which $\varphi(a)$ is the smallest possible, then $A/\left<a\right>$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

So far, I have proven that for all $b \in A$, if $b \notin <a>$, at least one of these cases happens: $(b-1) \in <a>$ or $(b+1) \in <a>$. I am trying to prove that these cases are mutual or exclusive, but I don't know how. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in A$. Then $x=aq+r$ with $r=0$ or $\varphi(r)<\varphi(a)$. If $r\ne0$ then $r$ is invertible, so $r=\pm1$. It follows $|A/(a)|\le3$.

Comment: Why does it follow?

Comment: @ÉtienneTétreault Since in $A/(a)$ we have $\bar x=\bar r$.

Comment: Actually I read the question again and I realize this is what I am trying to proove! Any reference for this statement? That would help me a lot!

Comment: @ÉtienneTétreault Which statement?

Comment: That in $A/(a)$ we have x¯=r¯

Comment: @ÉtienneTétreault Have you ever meet the [quotient rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring)?

Comment: Yes but for general rings not for Euclidean rings!

Comment: @ÉtienneTétreault And when do we have $\bar x=\bar y$ in $R/I$? (Here $\bar x$ denotes the residue class of $x$ modulo the ideal $I$.)

Comment: Damn I got it this is so obvious right now sorry for not seeing it before! Thanks!